# How does the gnome desktop start an application?

Tags: gnome

I am confused or curious about what happened when I click an app icon on desktop.

On Ubuntu 17.10, I run `firefox`, `gnome-terminal` and `gnome-calculator`, then I run `pstree` and see:

- `firefox` is a child of systemd(pid=1)
- `gnome-terminal` is a child of systemd(not pid=1) and has a `bash` child
- `gnome-calculator` is a child of `gnome-shell`

Why do they have different parent processes?

Comment: If firefox is a child of PID 1, something went wrong. Was it started by another user or in a crashed session?

Comment: I rechecked the pstree output. firefox is child of pid=1.